# What's needed for a browser, Safari and Opera in particular to understand an HTTP response?

Tags: python, http, httpresponse

I have an HTTP response of

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n
<!DOCTYPE html>...
```

Both Firefox and Chrome seem to understand it just fine and show the HTML content - however Safari and Opera just show me everything in plaintext. Adding a "Content-Type" field messes everything up for all browsers.

What's the catch?

I am not going to post the full code because there is a lot of arbitrary programming logic not related to the issue, however, what happens is something like this:

I create a socket, then all the related socket operations occur - all this works like magic, then after all the processing I .send(' response here ') and for some reason it only shows on Firefox and Chrome.

The response string looks like this:

```
'''
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
...
</html>
'''
```

This is what I am seeing:
http://cl.ly/0y0U1s0G3X2v1C11282S

Comment: Can you show exactly how you were adding the `Content-Type`?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you sending the characters `\r\n` or are you sending carriage return (byte value 13) and then newline (byte value 10)?

Comment: What's shown above is what I am sending using socket.send(). So yes \r\n. @gnibbler "Content-Type:text/html"

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought I did! Nonetheless, still having the same issue, I tried everything already.

Comment: Would you please post (a) the relevant header-sending part of your actual source code, and (b) a raw dump of the packets on the wire. Something is not quite right, and that information will help narrow down what it is.

Comment: How would I get the raw dump of packets?

Comment: Use a tool such as tcpdump or wireshark. But you could start by posting your code, that would help a lot.

Comment: It looks like you're sending the entire thing *within* the HTTP response body. Are you able to include the entire context of the code? Something looks quite off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You state that you are sending a literal string like:

```
'''
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
'''
```

However, Python only adds a single `\n` corresponding to a newline in a triple-quoted string. So the bytes that are sent end up being

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\n<!DOCTYPE html>...
```

As you can see, there is a missing `\r`. I suggest you use code like the following:

```
sock.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n")
```

In the above, you may want to add a `Content-type` header:

```
sock.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n\r\n")
```

Then, after sending the header, send the document payload:

```
sock.send('''
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
''')
```

This separates the protocol-level header from the data payload, and makes your code easier to understand. It's also easier to get the `\r\n` right in the header, since that's where it matters.

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't realize that the triple quotes were doing that! I am new to python.